# Unity3d freeze after show Interstitial on iOs8

Tags: unity-game-engine, ios8, iad, freeze, interstitial

After show and close an Interstitial banner on ios8, the app freeze.

The app back to full operate after pressing Home button and re-activate it.

I'm working with unity 4.5.4f1, xcode6. This is the pseudo code that we're using:

```
...

ADInterstitialAd.onInterstitialWasLoaded += OnFullscreenLoaded;

...

private ADInterstitialAd fullscreenAd=null;
fullscreenAd = new ADInterstitialAd(true);

...

void OnFullscreenLoaded()
{
    if(!fullscreenAd.loaded)     return;
    fullscreenAd.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue of unity fixed on 4.5.6

http://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/the-app-freezes-after-closing-an-adinterstitialad